# Reverse biorthogonal 2.2 wavelet inverse DWT implementation

Tags: c, matlab, wavelet, wavelet-transform

I have some image data that are - supposedly - transformed using the MATLAB’s 5/3 Le Gall integer lifting wavelet transformation. The actual Matlab code that does the inverse DWT calls the following function:

```
liftwave('rbio2.2')
```

It takes as input 4 128x128 matrices (LL, HL, LH, HH) and the wavelet (called LS from lifting scheme) and returns an image that is 252x252 pixels. I don't know if it adds any padding before doing the inverse DWT nor if the resulting image size is normal for this type of wavelet.

I am looking for an implementation of the particular wavelet inverse DWT outside Matlab. I have tried pywavelets but the resulting images are different (wrong).

Can anyone suggest an open source implementation?

**UPDATE**

I have found (one of the many) the [following implementation of the bior2.2](https://github.com/xbarin02/libdwt/blob/master/src/libdwt.c#L11749) wavelet with integer to integer mapping:

```
void dwt_cdf53_i_ex_stride_i(
    const int *src_l,
    const int *src_h,
    int *dst,
    int *tmp,
    int N,
    int stride)
{
    assert( N >= 0 && NULL != src_l && NULL != src_h && NULL != dst && NULL != tmp && 0 != stride );

    // fix for small N
    if(N < 2)
        return;

    // copy src into tmp
    dwt_util_memcpy_stride_i(tmp+0, 2*sizeof(int), src_l, stride,  ceil_div2(N));
    dwt_util_memcpy_stride_i(tmp+1, 2*sizeof(int), src_h, stride, floor_div2(N));

    // backward update 1 + backward predict 1
    for(int i=2; i<N-(N&1); i+=2)
        tmp[i] -= ( (tmp[i-1] + tmp[i+1]) + 2 ) >> 2;

    tmp[0] -= (tmp[1] + 1) >> 1;

    if(is_odd(N))
        tmp[N-1] -= (tmp[N-2] + 1) >> 1;
    else
        tmp[N-1] += tmp[N-2];

    for(int i=1; i<N-2+(N&1); i+=2)
        tmp[i] += ( tmp[i-1] + tmp[i+1] ) >> 1;

    // copy tmp into dst
    dwt_util_memcpy_stride_i(dst, stride, tmp, sizeof(int), N);
}
```

How can this be changed to perform the reverse biorthogonal wavelet?

Comment: Questions seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more on StackOverflow are considered [off-topic](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251134/where-can-i-ask-about-finding-a-tool-library-or-favorite-off-site-resource). Such questions can be answered on [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) SE site.

Comment: @rahnema1 I have rephrased my question asking for a way to modify the particular code snippet so that it performs the rbio2.2 inverse DWT instead of the bior2.2.

Answer (score 1):

Inverse transform with reverse biorthogonal spline wavelet (rbio2.2) is the same as forward transform with biorthogonal wavelet (bior2.2). From the top of my head, the code for the integer-to-integer inverse transform with reverse wavelet should look like this:

```c
void dwt_rcdf53_i_ex_stride_i(
    const int *src_l,
    const int *src_h,
    int *dst,
    int *tmp,
    int N,
    int stride)
{
    assert( N >= 0 && NULL != src_l && NULL != src_h && NULL != dst && NULL != tmp && 0 != stride );

    // fix for small N
    if(N < 2)
        return;

    // copy src into tmp
    dwt_util_memcpy_stride_i(tmp+0, 2*sizeof(int), src_l, stride,  ceil_div2(N));
    dwt_util_memcpy_stride_i(tmp+1, 2*sizeof(int), src_h, stride, floor_div2(N));

    // predict 1 + update 1
    for(int i=1; i<N-2+(N&1); i+=2)
        tmp[i] -= (tmp[i-1] + tmp[i+1]) >> 1;

    if(is_odd(N))
        tmp[N-1] += (tmp[N-2] + 1) >> 1;
    else
        tmp[N-1] -= tmp[N-2];

    tmp[0] += (tmp[1] + 1) >> 1;

    for(int i=2; i<N-(N&1); i+=2)
        tmp[i] += ((tmp[i-1] + tmp[i+1]) + 2) >> 2;

    // copy tmp into dst
    dwt_util_memcpy_stride_i(dst, stride, tmp, sizeof(int), N);
}
```

Comment: This was what I was getting with the bior2.2 code https://pasteboard.co/JzecRnG.bmp
and this is what I get with your code https://pasteboard.co/Jzedajs.bmp

Do you think that I am somehow wrong, and the image is actually transformed with the bior2.2 and not the rbio2.2?

My issue is that I see some artifacts that the original Matlab code doesn't have.

Comment: It is hard to say. In general, the libdwt library is not compatible with MATLAB. The positions of the L and H coefficients may differ. Also, the memory layout may differ. You should decompose and then compose the image using the same library.

Comment: You can try this: `/* predict */ for(int i=2; i<N-1; i+=2) tmp[i] -= (tmp[i-1] + tmp[i+1]) >> 1;` and `/* update */ for(int i=1; i<N-1; i+=2) tmp[i] += ((tmp[i-1] + tmp[i+1]) + 2) >> 2;` But I'm not sure if that's the problem.